# d3.js example works on example website but not on my server?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I copied the html and tsv example from this page directly http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 over to my server, but when I access it on my server, all I see is the y-axis. There are a bunch of errors in the javascript console:

```
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,135.1004464285714LNaN,137.4441964285714CNaN,139.7879464285714,NaN,144.47544642857142,NaN,147.48883928571428CNaN,150.50223214285714,NaN,151.84151785714283,NaN,152.76227678571428CNaN,153.6830357142857,NaN,154.18526785714283,NaN,154.52008928571428CNaN,154.85491071428572,NaN,155.02232142857142,NaN,156.52901785714283CNaN,158.03571428571428,NaN,160.8816964285714,NaN,162.55580357142856CNaN,164.22991071428567,NaN,164.7321428571428,NaN,164.89955357142853CNaN,165.06696428571425,NaN,164.89955357142856,NaN,164.89955357142856CNaN,164.89955357142856,NaN,165.06696428571425,NaN,162.30468749999997CNaN,159.54241071428567,NaN,153.8504464285714,NaN,150.1674107142857CNaN,146.48437499999997,NaN,144.81026785714283,NaN,143.63839285714283CNaN,142.46651785714283,NaN,141.79687499999997,NaN,139.11830357142856CNaN,136.4397321428571,NaN,131.7522321428571,NaN,127.06473214285714CNaN,122.37723214285712,NaN,117.68973214285712,NaN,117.43861607142857CNaN,117.1875,NaN,121.37276785714286,NaN,125.97656249999999CNaN,130.58035714285714,NaN,135.60267857142853,NaN,138.53236607142853CNaN,141.46205357142853,NaN,142.2991071428571,NaN,144.30803571428567CNaN,146.31696428571425,NaN,149.4977678571428,NaN,151.33928571428567CNaN,153.18080357142853,NaN,153.68303571428567,NaN,155.35714285714283CNaN,157.03124999999997,NaN,159.8772321428571,NaN,161.96986607142856CNaN,164.06249999999997,NaN,165.40178571428572,NaN,162.47209821428572CNaN,159.54241071428572,NaN,152.34374999999997,NaN,145.0613839285714CNaN,137.77901785714283,NaN,130.41294642857142,NaN,130.24553571428572CNaN,130.078125,NaN,137.109375,NaN,144.64285714285714CNaN,152.17633928571428,NaN,160.21205357142856,NaN,165.48549107142856CNaN,170.75892857142856,NaN,173.27008928571428,NaN,173.27008928571428CNa.....(not these numbers don't match the numbers in the tsv file, so I don't know where they're coming from)
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,450LNaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,4(ditto don't know where these numbers are coming from
Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,450LNaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,450CNaN,450,NaN,450,NaN,4...ditto
Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute transform="translate(NaN,173.27008928571425)"o @ d3.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ d3.min.js:3Y @ d3.min.js:1_a.each @ d3.min.js:3_a.attr @ d3.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ index2.html:121(anonymous function) @ d3.min.js:1t @ d3.min.js:1u @ d3.min.js:1
d3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute transform="translate(NaN,450)"o @ d3.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ d3.min.js:3Y @ d3.min.js:1_a.each @ d3.min.js:3_a.attr @ d3.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ index2.html:121(anonymous function) @ d3.min.js:1t @ d3.min.js:1u @ d3.min.js:1
d3.min.js:1 Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute transform="translate(NaN,88.89508928571426)"
```

All these numbers that appear in the error don't match anything in the .tsv file or in the code, so I don't know where they are coming from.

I have tried downloading the d3.mins.js onto my own server and sourcing it locally, but that didn't change anything. Also, looking at the network tab on my browser, I see that the data.tsv and d3.min.js files load instantly with 200 statuses, so they are not the problem. What else should I be trying? This is my first time working with d3.js, so I'd appreciate any recommendations.

Here's where I'm hosting the page:
http://sunnysideworks.nyc/d3/index2.html

Comment: Can you share the link to your server where you're having problems?

Comment: @Alex just added the link.

Comment: It looks like the x ordinate is the problem. This is the date. Could be that your system is not parsing the dates properly.

Comment: @CoolBlue My understanding is limited, but I thought all javascript embedded in html should execute client-side, in which case the controlling environment should be my browser and have nothing to do with my server?

Comment: Yes, but it's to do with the dates... see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your data, the date member is being run together with your first temperature, for example the first date is being interpreted as 
`date: "20111001 63.4"` which is not parsing.  Probably your data doesn't have a tab between the first and second column.

Comment: you were right, but it's because my .tsv is not properly formatted. It looks fine but for some reason the first 2 columns are separated by a bunch of spaces while the last 2 columns are truly separated by tabs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it's amazing what you can figure out with an open mind ;p